# csv file not opening in standard view in OpenOffice

Tags: excel, csv, jenkins, openoffice-basic

I am running a tool in Jenkins, which reads a .csv file. The computer I'm using doesn't have Microsoft Office installed, just OpenOffice.

Compared to Excel, OpenOffice opens this file in a strange view, for example:

- connects a few columns to one column;
- splits one line to many columns;
- does not show columns titles.

[image: screenshot]

I wonder if anyone has encountered this issue and can advise me.

Comment: Inserted image from link.

Comment: What import settings did you use when opening the file?  For one thing, it looks like you told Calc to split based on spaces -- was this intentional?  Please give specific examples of the desired results versus actual results.  Such as, "XXYY was split into two columns XX and YY, but it should be in a single column."  Additionally, tell the version of OpenOffice.  Regarding column titles, show how they look in the .csv file when viewed with a text editor, and describe how they should look in Calc.

Comment: the columns category dont showed ( like- Line, Rank, atc.. ). column D is mutual to column C and E. from column c it need to be one line. for example row 1: column D need to be "range check". column x need to be: "range check might fail, .... ".